# Website Login hidden in IE but working in chrome

Tags: css

I cannot figure out why my website login form is part hidden in IE, but looks OK in Chrome???

Link is here

http://make-your-offer.com/

Any guidance would be appreciated!

I'm REALLY struggling styling that login form - I want to release the website for people to start registering, but at the moment I'm not a fan of how it looks!

:( can anyone help me, I tried ALL last night and been trying a couple of hours already today :(

Comment: Just a tip, try to make your titles more descriptive. It helps people figure out if they are able to help or not.

Answer (score 2):

Your site is missing a DOCTYPE and thus is firing in Quirks mode in IE. Add a proper DOCTYPE and everything works fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: Where would I add that?? Doesn't appear to have fixed it

Comment: @MichaelStott you add that at **the very first line** of your html index page, before any content.

Comment: @Michael Stott the doctype should be the very FIRST line of your html file\

Comment: @MichaelStott just took a look at your page and is all out of whack, you have multiple `<head>` declarations in your html and your `<html>` declaration (including the DOCTYPE) starts all the way down at the bottom after the `<head>` section. I suggest you [you read up](http://htmldog.com/guides/htmlbeginner/) on proper markup, afterwards you should end up with [something like this](http://htmldog.com/guides/htmlbeginner/conclusion/).

Answer (score 1):

```
#my-mega-menu-widget {
   margin-top: -20px;
}
```

that is (probably) what's causing it.

you can use a [IE conditional comments](http://davidwalsh.name/ie-conditional-comments) or [css hack to fix it for IE](http://dimox.net/personal-css-hacks-for-ie6-ie7-ie8/) to overwrite that value.

or as sven suggests, refactor your code so you don't have to use a negative margin (they *are* bad mojo)

---

If you're using IE7 it won't draw the part of an element that sticks out of its parent if you're using negative margins to pull the element that way (though `overflow: visible` should work).

This is a "hasLayout" related IE bug, and a treatment for it can be found at [Has Layout: Negative Margin Bug.](http://haslayout.net/css/Negative-Margin-Bug)

Comment: if a negative margin is needed to make the layout working n chrome the he should not make a hack for IE, then he should look at his layout and make something better.

Comment: Removing the negative sorted it in IE, but now the login is slighlty hidden under the main box on Chrome..